# Getting always status unavailble from xmpp in android

Tags: android, xmpp

Getting availabilty always unavailable either user is offline or online on openfire server

```
Roster roster = xmppConnection1.getRoster();
Presence _availability = roster.getPresence(TO);
Log.i("_availability===>", "_availability ===> "+ _availability);
```